# File name is now red and I can't find it

Tags: files, directory, locate

I did this

```
mv -f bashthings /playinhere/
```

to move a directory "Bashthings" and all of it's files into another directory "Playinhere". Now I can't see Bashthings and when I "locate" it, it shows up, but it's in red. What did I do wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: run `sudo updatedb; locate bashthings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could run:

`find -name bashthings`

No need to update a database.

Further reading

- [find(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Answer (score 1):

locate is not updated real time. Are you sure bashthings was a directory?. Run

```
sudo updatedb
```

to update the database and locate will find the file again but this time also the location where it is on disc.

By the way. Looking at what you did then ...

```
cd /playinhere/bashthings/
```

should get you to the directory you moved.

Comment: Why do I not see any info about locate reporting such files in red at its man page?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably moved a symbolic link, which is now broken. Depending upon which file it referred to, you can recreate the symbolic link using `ln -s` command.